# HEAD headers differ from GET, chunked transfer

Tags: http, standards, haproxy

A web application under test behaves in an odd way. A `HEAD` request returns the header `Content-Length`, but the consequent `GET` returns `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. I expected the headers to be equal, and [RFC says SHOULD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4), so my question is: how legit and how common is this behaviour?

**UPDATE** It turns out, that the root cause of the problem is HAProxy's behaviour. If that's a `HEAD` request, the response is propagated as is from the application underneath. But for `GET` it applies the compression and sets the chunked transfer. I'll close this question as an off-topic and perhaps will ask at ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

If the server use chunked encoding for GET, but returns Content-Length for HEAD this is IMHO an indication that the information returned for HEAD is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: The `Content-Length` value is definitely correct in my case.

Comment: Well, in that case the server does extra work for calculating the length on HEAD, but does not on GET. It's certainly strange.

Comment: I agree with @JulianReschke: servers generally have more information available in GET requests because they naturally must expend at least as much effort to generate the response as they do with a POST request. Conversely, servers should want to spend as little time as possible on HEAD requests.

If the HEAD response includes an accurate Content-Length, there's no reason that the corresponding GET response does not also (chunked encoding pretty much means "it's too expensive to calculate the total Content-Length")

Answer (score 0):

The `HEAD` method response does not return entity-body but `GET` responds with an entity-body, if the HTTP server has the `"Chunked transfer encoding"` enabled does not send the `"Content-Length"` in the response because is not used, the server does not need to know the length of the content before it starts transmitting a response to the client. The server can begin transmitting dynamically-generated content to the client before knowing the total size of that content. Perhaps this is the most likely explanation.

Comment: Yes, `Content-Length` and chunked encoding are mutually exclusive, but can the result be different for `HEAD` and `GET` in this respect?

Comment: I am not really sure, RFC says should be identical, but with chuncked transfer enabled seems not.